# Android: how to loop through Firebase Datasnapshot and store keys in class level array list?

Tags: android, arrays, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very new to Java, so apologies upfront if this is super straight forward.

I'm tying to loop through my Firebase database and store key set of every child in an ArrayList.

Here is the short version of the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mRefEvents;
private List<String> newArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRefEvents = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https:***");
    newArray = new ArrayList<String>();


    mRefEvents.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                for (DataSnapshot grandChild : child.getChildren())
                {
                    newArray.add(grandChild.getKey());
                }
            }
            Log.i("App info middle", newArray.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {
        }
    });

    Log.i("App info end", newArray.toString());
}
}
```

When I log ("App info middle") newArray within `addValueEventListener` method, I get exactly the values I need. However, the second log ("App info end") at the bottom, gives me an empty array and doesn't store keys into ArrayList newArray.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are running everything in one go.  Since the listener runs asynchronously, I imagine that you are hitting the Log at the bottom "App Info End" before you are hitting the Log in the listener "App Info Middle". Try running "App info End" in a different method or after a button click and you should see the Array populated.  Having said all this, can you post your output to the Console so we can confirm that the App Info End is being hit before App info Middle?

Comment: You were absolutely right Alexander.  Here is the console output

Comment: 12-26 20:02:13.175 8247-8247/com.example.kaznaur.simafirebasetrial I/App info end: []
12-26 20:02:14.259 8247-8247/com.example.kaznaur.simafirebasetrial I/App info middle: [Debates, Speach, Bachelor, Housewives, Voice, Football]
12-26 20:02:20.760 8247-8247/com.example.kaznaur.simafirebasetrial I/App info buttonClick: [Debates, Speach, Bachelor, Housewives, Voice, Football]
12-26 20:02:30.311 8247-8247/com.example.kaznaur.simafirebasetrial I/App info buttonClick: [Debates, Speach, Bachelor, Housewives, Voice, Football]

Comment: That used to trip me up at first when using Firebase.  Glad to have got it rolling for you.